# UNION ALL to combine data across companies, with tables of same expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, while-loop, union-all

Is there by any chance a possibility to combine/union data from multiple tables, ending on the same characters in a SELECT statement?

We have several companies, built up with the same tables, and also the same column setup within the tables. For me to not making a UNION all statement, that includes all of the stores, I would like to know, if I could make a script, which does this for me.

Example of tables:

```
[Database].[dbo].[Company1$Sales Line]
[Database].[dbo].[Company2$Sales Line]
[Database].[dbo].[Company3$Sales Line]...
```

How I write the script today:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Company1$Sales Line]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Company2$Sales Line]
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Company3$Sales Line]...
```

I would think that there is an easier solution to do this.
Could probably be a WHILE loop statement - but I have no idea, what is the best practice, and if it's even possible. Otherwise I should make a VBA in Excel to assist me in doing this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: is `[database]` really a schema name?

Comment: Ah sorry... Nope [Database].[dbo]

Comment: Seems like storing the data in a *single* table, with a CompanyId to differentiate sales, would be simpler.  Failing that, create a VIEW using UNION ALL that joins the results together.

Comment: ... and while it could probably be done programmatically, I'd hope adding a new company is an infrequent enough occurrence that a [VIEW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15) would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after a way to generate the SQL you need on the fly, you can use the following as a basis, perhaps to build the content of a view which you can then query. Also note that generally, you don't specify *3 part* names as you connect to the database in question. It's different of course for multiple databases, but that doesn't seem to be the case given your sample data.

```
select String_Agg(Concat('select * from ', QuoteName(Schema_Name(schema_id)), '.', QuoteName(name)), ' union all' + Char(13))
from sys.tables
where schema_id=Schema_Id('dbo') and name like 'Company%$Sales Line';
```